# How to import moment.js into vue

Tags: date, vue.js, datepicker

I am trying to use moment.js within a very simple vue build. I have added moment.js to the body of my index page, but when i try to use moment.js I keep getting the console error "ReferenceError: moment is not defined".

```
// registering the date picker
  components: {
    vuejsDatepicker,
},    


// the component with some props 
<vuejs-datepicker
                    :value="this.default"
                    name="datepicker"
                    :clear-button="true"
                    :typeable="true"
                    v-model="GetPaymentDate"
                    :format="customFormatter"
                    input-class="form-control"
                    ></vuejs-datepicker>

 methods: {

 // the method to produce formated date
    customFormatter(date) {
      return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    }
},

// where Im trying to display formated date - this is the bit that breaks things - the | formatDate
<p>The delivery Date is <b>{{ GetPaymentDate | formatDate}}</b></p>


// the order of my scripts on the index file 
<script src="vue-moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"> . </script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
```

Comment: Just add the moment library as a dependency (another `<script>`).  I don't think it's included by default.

Comment: .... thanks - I cant believe I missed that - Doh!

Answer (score 1):

simply add the below line. you can add it inside the main.js or the component file

import moment from 'moment';